# create subgroups as new variable

Tags: r

Is there a convinient way to generate new variables that contain subtypes. (for analysis)

E.g. we have `smoker` status, `sex` and `lifeQuality`.

Lets say we want to test smoker-female vs non-smoker-female in respect to `lifeQuality`

Is there a convinient and !general way! to get my desired subgroups (`femaleSmoker` and `maleSmoker`)?

```
set.seed(1337)
df <- data.frame(smoker=sample(c("yes","no"),10,replace = T),sex=sample(c("male","female"),10,replace = T),lifeQuality=rnorm(10))

df$femaleSmoker <- paste0(df$sex,"_",df$smoker)
df$femaleSmoker[df$sex=="male"] <- NA

df$maleSmoker <- paste0(df$sex,"_",df$smoker)
df$maleSmoker[df$sex=="female"] <- NA

> df
   smoker    sex lifeQuality femaleSmoker maleSmoker
1      no   male   1.0467758         <NA>    male_no
2     yes female   0.7706077   female_yes       <NA>
3     yes   male   0.3980541         <NA>   male_yes
4      no female  -0.3171052    female_no       <NA>
5      no female  -1.3180397    female_no       <NA>
6     yes   male   1.0174820         <NA>   male_yes
7      no   male  -1.6237908         <NA>    male_no
8     yes   male  -0.5703763         <NA>   male_yes
9     yes   male   0.3104756         <NA>   male_yes
10     no   male  -2.6101319         <NA>    male_no
>
```

Comment: I am not understanding the question. What is wrong with current output?

Comment: nothing is wrong. I was searching for a fast way to generate new columns with subtypes like in the above example. I was wondering if there already existed a solution for this. I made a function that does the above with minimal effort.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

general solution

```
fast.subgroups <- function(x,groups) {
    groupsList <- strsplit(groups, "\\+")
    for (i in length(groupsList):1) {
        var <- groupsList[[i]]
        lvl1 <- levels(factor(x[var[1]][,1]))
        for(ii in length(lvl1):1) {
            tmp <- paste(x[,var[1]],var[2],x[,var[2]],sep="_")
            tmp[!(x[var[1]]==lvl1[ii])] <- NA
            strCmd <- paste0("x <- cbind(",var[1],"_",lvl1[ii],"_",var[2],"=","tmp,x,stringsAsFactors = F)")
            eval(parse(text = strCmd))
        }
    }
    return(x)
}
```

data:

```
set.seed(1337)
n =15
df <- data.frame(smoker=sample(c("yes","no"),n,replace = T),sex=sample(c("male","female"),n,replace = T),ill=sample(c("mild","moderate","severe"),n,replace = T),lifeQuality=rnorm(n),stringsAsFactors = F)
```

apply function:

```
fast.subgroups(x=df,groups=c("sex+smoker","ill+sex"))
```

results:

```
   sex_female_smoker sex_male_smoker    ill_mild_sex    ill_moderate_sex    ill_severe_sex smoker    sex      ill lifeQuality
1               <NA>  male_smoker_no            <NA>                <NA>   severe_sex_male     no   male   severe -1.32964336
2   female_smoker_no            <NA> mild_sex_female                <NA>              <NA>     no female     mild -0.18078626
3  female_smoker_yes            <NA>            <NA>                <NA> severe_sex_female    yes female   severe -0.32265873
4               <NA> male_smoker_yes   mild_sex_male                <NA>              <NA>    yes   male     mild  0.55766293
5               <NA> male_smoker_yes            <NA>                <NA>   severe_sex_male    yes   male   severe -0.23733258
6  female_smoker_yes            <NA>            <NA> moderate_sex_female              <NA>    yes female moderate -0.58239712
7   female_smoker_no            <NA>            <NA>                <NA> severe_sex_female     no female   severe  0.22477526
8               <NA> male_smoker_yes            <NA>                <NA>   severe_sex_male    yes   male   severe  0.42577251
9               <NA> male_smoker_yes   mild_sex_male                <NA>              <NA>    yes   male     mild -0.66224169
10 female_smoker_yes            <NA> mild_sex_female                <NA>              <NA>    yes female     mild  1.49037322
11  female_smoker_no            <NA>            <NA>                <NA> severe_sex_female     no female   severe -1.11923261
12  female_smoker_no            <NA>            <NA>                <NA> severe_sex_female     no female   severe  0.06867219
13  female_smoker_no            <NA>            <NA> moderate_sex_female              <NA>     no female moderate  0.12729929
14              <NA> male_smoker_yes            <NA>   moderate_sex_male              <NA>    yes   male moderate  0.83248241
15  female_smoker_no            <NA> mild_sex_female                <NA>              <NA>     no female     mild -1.51970610
>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try `case_when` from `dplyr`:

```
library(dplyr)
df <- data.frame(smoker=sample(c("yes","no"),10,replace = T),sex=sample(c("male","female"),10,replace = T),lifeQuality=rnorm(10))
df%>%
mutate(subcat=case_when(
 .$smoker == "yes" & .$sex == "male"   ~ "maleSmoker",
 .$smoker == "no"  & .$sex == "male"   ~ "maleNonSmoker",
 .$smoker == "yes" & .$sex == "female" ~ "femaleSmoker",
. $smoker == "no"  & .$sex == "female" ~ "femaleNonSmoker"))

   smoker    sex lifeQuality          subcat
1      no   male    1.969426   maleNonSmoker
2     yes   male    1.192345      maleSmoker
3     yes   male   -0.762863      maleSmoker
4      no   male   -1.259429   maleNonSmoker
5     yes female   -2.423066    femaleSmoker
6      no   male    0.249120   maleNonSmoker
7      no female   -0.455351 femaleNonSmoker
8     yes female   -1.623958    femaleSmoker
9      no   male    0.680503   maleNonSmoker
10    yes   male   -1.374085      maleSmoker
```

If you want two columns for `female` and `male` like you have in your question:

```
df%>%
mutate(femaleSmoker =case_when(
 .$smoker == "yes" & .$sex == "female" ~ "female_yes",
. $smoker == "no"  & .$sex == "female" ~ "female_no"),
maleSmoker =case_when(
 .$smoker == "yes" & .$sex == "male"   ~ "male_yes",
 .$smoker == "no"  & .$sex == "male"   ~ "male_no"
))

   smoker    sex lifeQuality femaleSmoker maleSmoker
1      no   male    1.969426         <NA>    male_no
2     yes   male    1.192345         <NA>   male_yes
3     yes   male   -0.762863         <NA>   male_yes
4      no   male   -1.259429         <NA>    male_no
5     yes female   -2.423066   female_yes       <NA>
6      no   male    0.249120         <NA>    male_no
7      no female   -0.455351    female_no       <NA>
8     yes female   -1.623958   female_yes       <NA>
9      no   male    0.680503         <NA>    male_no
10    yes   male   -1.374085         <NA>   male_yes
```